# Will mineral spirits reduce the appearance of lap marks on a stained floor?

Tags: wood, flooring, stain

we used the Minwax All In One water-based floor stain on a very large area of flooring.  The starting and stopping caused dark blotchy stains all over my floor. We tried going over it again and it really did not help and possibly made it worse. Is there any way to make it even.  Can I use mineral spirits or water?  any ideas would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Have you called Minwax? They have a tech line. Ihave never used that product but itis possible that rewetting the finish with more of the same will allow you to redistibute the lap marks...but call minwax. They may have you thin it or use a different applicator, etc.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'd be successful with that approach. It would be very difficult to dissolve and wipe off specific areas and effectively taper it out. That's *if* the mineral spirits will dissolve cured urethane, which I doubt. Then, you'd have to reapply clear urethane to create a smooth finish.

You may need to sand the floor again and reapply. A product like that [must be applied in a single wet application](https://www.minwax.com/wood-products/hardwood-floors/minwax-complete-1step-floor-finish). For more forgiveness, stain and varnish separately. It's fairly hard to mess up a wiping stain, and clear urethane won't usually leave lap marks.